# Loading seven container in a single Viewcontroller consuming more time

Tags: xcode, containers, viewcontroller

i am having a viewController which consist of 7 container in it. the view controller consist of tabbar with 7 buttons. clicking each button will display the respective container. But 7 container loads huge data from server so opening the viewcontroller consume more time.

now i want to load the container only when the respective button is clicked..so please help me.

Comment: What code have you written yourself to try and do this? Please don't just ask people to do the work for you. Tell us what you've tried and what didn't work, to demonstrate that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from giving obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below methods which are help to load the respective page api's or methods when you click the buttons, They are,

```
    1. NSNotification
    2. Class Method
    3. Instance Method
    4. Delegate Methods
```

Comment: can you elaborate it with an example??

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question.